# Find acceleration at the first instant when a car has zero velocity.

Tags: derivatives, physics, mathematical-physics

The position of the front bumper of a test car under microprocessor control is given by:

$x(t)=2.17m+\left(4.8\frac{m}{s^2}\right)t^2-\left(.100\frac{m}{s^6}\right)t^6$

Find its acceleration at the first instant when the car has zero velocity.

So I'm having trouble understanding where to start.  I believe I need to take the derivative of the equation, but how do I find its acceleration when the car has zero velocity?

Any tips to get me started are greatly appreciated!

Comment: (i) Find $x'(t)$; (ii) Find the "first" time $a$ when $x'(a)=0$; (iii) Find $x''(t)$ and then $x''(a)$.

Comment: The "first" time when velocity is $0$ is when $9.6 t=0.6 t^5$. This happens at the negative root of $t^4=16$, that is, at $t=-2$.

Comment: Although I consider it a sloppy practice, I think it is intended that the position function is implicitly applied for $ \ t \ > \ 0 \ , $ even though it doesn't say so.  In that case, we do want the _positive_ fourth-root of 16 (since, otherwise, the first time would still be $ \ t \ = \ 0 \ . $

Comment: @AndréNicolas the follow up to this question is 'Find its position at the second instant when the car has zero velocity.'  How do I find that if the velocity is 0 at only one instant?

Comment: The equation $x'(t)=0$ has three solutions, $-2$, $0$, and $2$. I do not know whether implicitly $t\ge 0$, answers change if we allow negative $t$. If $t=0$ is first instant, $t=2$ is the second. If $t=-2$ is considered the first instant, the second is $t=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x(t)=2.17m+\left(4.8\frac{m}{s^2}\right)t^2-\left(.100\frac{m}{s^6}\right)t^6\\
v(t)=\left(9.6\right)t-\left(0.600\right)t^5$$
$v(t)=0$ when $t=0$ (first instant). So, 
$$a(0)=\left(9.6\frac{m}{s^2}\right)$$
This is indeed the magnitude of the gravitational acceleration.

Comment: I got a similar answer and it says that this is incorrect :(

Comment: @inquisitor It would be helpful if you were able to hint where I went wrong.

Comment: Twice $4.8$ is not $9.8$. And the derivative is not right.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks. The first was a typo, and I corrected the units of the derivative.

Comment: Sanatha, I would love to tell you but I have no idea!  That's why I'm asking the question :-P

Comment: You want to _differentiate_ that $ \ t^6 \ $ , rather than _raising_ its exponent....

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Oh! Silly me - I'll change it.

Comment: Oh, and there is no reason for the acceleration to have anything to do with Earth surface gravity: it appears simply to be the result of the problem poser's choice of numbers. Presumably, this test car is traveling along the ground...

Comment: Yeah, I know - just an interesting coincidence!